# Google Pay sandbox access for Google Pay on the web

Tags: payment, sandbox, google-pay

I am working on integrating Google Pay into my web application and I was wondering if there is any way to use the [Google Pay sandbox environment](https://pay.sandbox.google.com) for testing purposes. Currently in the payments client I am just specifying that the environment is test:

```
var paymentsClient = new google.payments.api.PaymentsClient({environment: 'TEST'});
```

but the above doesn't reach the sandbox environment. Also, there seems to be no other way to specify the environment apart from the above line of code.

Comment: The only [supported environments](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/web/reference/request-objects#PaymentOptions) are `TEST` and `PRODUCTION`.